# Setting a base import directory in Angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm developing an `Angular2` app using version `2.0.0-beta.7` in combination with `TypeScript`. I started with putting all my `.ts` files in one directory, just for reaching the needed functionality. Now I'm trying to organize them logically with a directory structure, that covers the logic of my application and it's functionality. After doing this I got a lot of lines like this:

```js
import {Config} from '../../../../../config/app-config';
```

... and this...

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'traffic-info',
    templateUrl: '../../../../../../views/traffic-info.html'
})
```

All these `../` are a bit annoying, but as far as I know, the path values have to be relative to the current script. So, I was wondering if there is a way to set something like a default (base) import path or something like this, and skip all these 'one level up' steps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a `base` tag in the head of you HTML page:

> The HTML `<base>` element specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document. There can be only one `<base>` element in a document.

Something like that:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="some root path">
    (...)
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this option, but I was wondering if there would be a problem with the routing if I change it. According to [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#-lt-base-href-) article the `base` element is used from the router for composing the URLs.

Comment: Yes! I think that it's also apply for `templateUrl` paths but not for SystemJS module paths...